# Flex form configuration in controller - typo3

Tags: typo3, typoscript, extbase

I have a typo3 extension.I need to save the basic configuration using flex forms.So that i wrote a flex form.But can't access these values in controller.

My code is given below

ext_tables.php

```
$extensionName = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::underscoredToUpperCamelCase($_EXTKEY);
$frontendpluginName = 'userform'; //Your Front-end Plugin Name
$pluginSignature = strtolower($extensionName) . '_'.strtolower($frontendpluginName);
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['list']['subtypes_addlist'][$pluginSignature] = 'pi_flexform';
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPiFlexFormValue($pluginSignature, 'FILE:EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Configuration/FlexForms/user_flexform.xml');
```

user_flexform.xml

```
<T3DataStructure>
    <sheets>
        <sDEF>
            <ROOT>
                <TCEforms>
                    <sheetTitle>Data Table Config</sheetTitle>
                </TCEforms>
                <type>array</type>
                <el>

                   <switchableControllerActions>
                        <TCEforms>
                            <label>Phone Number Format</label>
                            <config>
                                <type >select</type>
                                <items name="settings.phone" type="array">
                                    <numIndex index="0" type="array">
                                           <numIndex index="0">US</numIndex>
                                           <numIndex index="1">(678) 567-1234</numIndex>
                                    </numIndex>
                                    <numIndex index="1" type="array">
                                        <numIndex index="0">India</numIndex>
                                        <numIndex index="1">+91 6789765434</numIndex>
                                    </numIndex>
                                </items>
                            </config>
                        </TCEforms>
                    </switchableControllerActions>
                </el>
            </ROOT>
        </sDEF>
    </sheets>
</T3DataStructure>
```

user_controller.php

```
$config = $this->settings;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `switchableControllerActions` is used to select an action. This is not a regular setting. Those are defined a bit different

```
<T3DataStructure>
    <sheets>
        <sDEF>
            <ROOT>
                <TCEforms>
                    <sheetTitle>Data Table Config</sheetTitle>
                </TCEforms>
                <type>array</type>
                <el>
                <switchableControllerActions>
                    <TCEforms>
                        <label>LLL:EXT:news/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:flexforms_general.mode</label>
                        <onChange>reload</onChange>
                        <config>
                            <type>select</type>
                            <items>
                                <numIndex index="1">
                                    <numIndex index="0">Company</numIndex>
                                    <numIndex index="1">Company->list;Company->show</numIndex>
                                </numIndex>
                                <numIndex index="2">
                                    <numIndex index="0">Product</numIndex>
                                    <numIndex index="1">Product->list;Product->show</numIndex>
                                </numIndex>
                            </items>
                        </config>
                    </TCEforms>
                </switchableControllerActions>   
                   <settings.phone>
                        <TCEforms>
                            <label>Phone Number Format</label>
                            <config>
                                <type >select</type>
                                <items>
                                    <numIndex index="0" type="array">
                                           <numIndex index="0">US</numIndex>
                                           <numIndex index="1">(678) 567-1234</numIndex>
                                    </numIndex>
                                    <numIndex index="1" type="array">
                                        <numIndex index="0">India</numIndex>
                                        <numIndex index="1">+91 6789765434</numIndex>
                                    </numIndex>
                                </items>
                            </config>
                        </TCEforms>
                    </settings.phone>
                </el>
            </ROOT>
        </sDEF>
    </sheets>
</T3DataStructure>
```

If you don't need the `switchableControllerActions`, then just remove it.

Be aware that once saving flexform with those can create side effects as those are still persisted even though you removed them in your flexforms. Therefore best is to remove the plugin and create a new one!

Comment: I got an array 

array(1 item)
   blog => array(1 item)
      max => '0' (1 chars)

Comment: @Georg Ringer Said a point.. If a configuration is changed from the flexform then still the old values are stored in corresponding tables in xml format. So better leave the current extension and build a new one .